# C script working in Loadrunner VuGen, but not PerformanceCenter

Tags: load, loadrunner, wsh, vugen

I have an issue where I have a compiled dll added to the script in VuGen in the user_init which runs perfectly. But when I create a zip, import the test into performance center, the script fails to execute.

Is there a way that I can upload the required dll into the loadGenerator?

Request directions as I am very new to LoadRunner.

Much thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, consult your version of LoadRunner regarding the concept "extra files" for a virtual user.  With the DLL as a part of the virtual user definition, it will be uploaded to the load generator.   You will likely need to change your loading context from where you are loading the DLL to a local script context versus your defined current physical location.

Be wary on the DLL front.  Many DLL's are designed with low usage client access in mind (less than a half a dozen sessions on the local machine).  Once you move into load generator territory you can get all sorts of locking and thread issues with a client side DLL that you would never experience in "normal" client usage because of the number of concurrent accesses to the library.

If you are not watching for this then you might consider the slowdowns to be a problem with your application under test.  I always recommend a "control generator," hardware matched to all of the other load generators but executing only one user of each type to act as a check against these load generator induced issues.   How this works is the following: If your control group and your global group slow or have errors in the same ratio, then you can be assured that a common external source is at fault.  This is most likely the application under test.  On the other hand, if your non control generators start slowing or experiencing a significant number of errors, but your control group remains constant in its performance, and perhaps even getting faster, then your issues is on your load generator and not your application under test.  It is better that you, as a performance tester, discover this than the developers for whom you have just called their child (code) ugly (defective).